# Spring cloud config Branch vs Profiles

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

We have started using `spring-cloud-config` to manage the configuration of our microservices.

We have DEV, INT, QA and PROD stages. What would be the better way to manage the configuration specific to stages?

- Using branches or
- Using profiles

Having it as the separate branch will be cleaner as configuration will not be cluttered in one place (my view). Any recommendations?

Comment: I would use branches. You wouldn't want prod config accidentally changed when changing dev.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb for the input. Thats really a main thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I have chose using `Branch` because of the following advantages

- Easier to manage the config
- Configuration files will be smaller as there will be config for each environment
- As spencergibb suggested, you wont change the production config if it is in the different branch

Comment: Could you add your configuration? (or at least a MWE)